# Is there a way to change your Minecraft username ( in Minecraft PE v0.15.0) WITHOUT changing your Xbox Live username/gamertag?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition, xbox-network

I was wondering if there was a way to change your Minecraft Pocket Edition (MCPE) username so that it isn't the same as your Xbox live username. I have Minecraft on the Pc and already, have a username I also used on the PE as well. But, when I updated the MCPE to v0.15.0 and signed into Xbox live, it changed my username (My Xbox live username is still the same). Is there anything I can do?

Thank you, and have a nice day!

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry but there is not currently a way to change your MCPE username if its been linked to your Xbox live username. I would just sign out of Xbox live to change it, if you do not want to maybe post the idea on Minecraft Forums and they might change it. ( ͡° ͜ʖ ͡°)﻿